# Dynamically Creating/Displaying Content on an ASP.Net Site

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, webforms

I find it ironic that I know how to store all of this data into a database, but regrettably have limited knowledge on how to display it to an end-user.

Basically, I'm programming an app, and on the main page I would like a Facebook style 'news feed' to appear.  People could post an event, user comments would show underneath it, and then give an opportunity for users to comment on it.  This page would show 10 most recent events (including comments), unless the user clicked on the bottom to load more.

***So, this goes into dynamically creating controls.  As I see it, for each event that appears, I need to:***
-Create label for the main event description

-Create label for each child comment

-create text box for a user to compose comment

-create button to submit comment

-attach event handler to said button

*And for the bottom of the page*

*Create button that keeps moving down the page once more comments are loaded and displayed

The last I really programmed dynamic ASP.net pages was about 4 years ago.  I remember recalling a control you could use that would refresh only the content in that panel - not the rest of the page - but I'm not sure if that's the way to go.

Could anyone give me a guide to how to program a dynamic page in ASP.Net?  I forgot how to make questions as community (because this is open-ended)....  I'm currently using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express w/ webforms.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this article about [Dynamically Create Controls in ASP.NET by Using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317794). Which describes about creating controls dynamically.
Also if you like to generate dynamic content from database, you can use the `literal`. Where you can append database content as string to the literal

Hope this helps